# Can vim set the path relative to its current working directory?

Tags: vim

I use the :find command to find files in `vim`. My path is set like so:

`set path=$PWD/**`

This works well until I use `:Explore` and the `c` mapping to update the CWD at which point the PWD and CWD are no longer the same. I need to set the path again after each directory change. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

P.S.

No plugins allowed =p

Comment: Netrw's `c` is used to change Vim's current directory to the "browsing directory" in netrw: it's similar to `:cd /path/to/some/directory`. If you don't want Vim's current directory to change, why do you use `c` in the first place?

Comment: @romainl I do want the cwd to change, but I also want the path to change. In my configuration, the path should be based on the cwd. What I really need it a function that gets called each time the cwd changes. This function would update my path, like in Ingo Karkat's example.

Comment: Then you simply want `set path=**` which will *always* be relative to the current directory: Start vim in `/path/a`, `:find` will find files in `/path/a/**`; `:cd /path/b`, `:find` will find files in `/path/b/**`. If you want to keep the `$PWD`, you can do `set path=$PWD,**`. `set path=**` is what I use, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following command to update your `'path'` option to the CWD.

```
let &path = getcwd() . '/**'
```

Unfortunately, there's no event for directory changes to hook into. You could either:

1. Override the mentioned `c` mapping in the *netrw* windows, with `:autocmd FileType netrw nnoremap <buffer> c ...`
2. Hook into some events that fire frequently, e.g. `:autocmd WinEnter,CursorHold ...` and invoke the above command then.

Comment: Actually I ended up going w/ set path=** and then using Command-T plugin as well

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `autochdir` to set on:

```
'autochdir' 'acd'   boolean (default off)
            global
            {not in Vi}
            {only available when compiled with it, use
            exists("+autochdir") to check}
    When on, Vim will change the current working directory whenever you
    open a file, switch buffers, delete a buffer or open/close a window.
    It will change to the directory containing the file which was opened
    or selected.
    This option is provided for backward compatibility with the Vim
    released with Sun ONE Studio 4 Enterprise Edition.
    Note: When this option is on some plugins may not work.
```

But this is buggy if you using `netrw` or `fugitive` for example.